# Android Wearable Data Layer won't sync.

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to use Data sync between watch and my phone but I am failing miserably on that.

Mobile side :

```
package com.off.testcomm;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setOnClickListener((Button) findViewById(R.id.button));

    initGoogleAPIClient();

}

private void setOnClickListener(Button button) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("OFF", "increase counter");
            PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
            putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt("COUNT_COUNT", 7);
            PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();

            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                            Log.i("OFF", "SaveConfig: " + dataItemResult.getStatus() + ", " + dataItemResult.getDataItem().getUri());
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}

private void initGoogleAPIClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                    Log.d("OFF", "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                    // Now you can use the Data Layer API
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                    Log.d("OFF", "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                    Log.d("OFF", "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                }
            })
                    // Request access only to the Wearable API
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

When I click the button I get :

```
SaveConfig: Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, wear://ad9cb4db-c697-4777-9088-0b29b8584043/count
```

So I assume it is sent.

On Wear :

```
package com.off.testcomm;

public class MyWatchFace extends CanvasWatchFaceService {

...

private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,DataApi.DataListener, MessageApi.MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

    @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {

          if (visible) {
            Log.i("OFF","is visible");
            registerReceiver();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
          } ...

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("OFF", "OnConnected ");

        Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i("OFF","onConnectionSuspended");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
        Log.i("OFF","OnDataChanged");

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Log.i("OFF","onMessageReceived");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i("OFF","onConnectionFailed");

    }

 ...
```

On wear last log I am getting is : "OnConnected" . When I click button on mobile nothing seems to be synced on wear.

As you can see both classes are in the same packages.

As for manifests both have :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

any ideas?

thanks

w.

Comment: On the sender side (phone), add a timestamp to your data and try again: 
putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
and see if that makes any difference. I suspect you are adding the same data and that doesn't count as a change, hence the onDataChanged is not called.

Comment: @AliNaddaf it seems it works,thanks. I need to make some tests to make sure, but why don't you submit it as an answer and if everything is fine I will close it with your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the same data each time the button is clicked, there is no "change" in the exiting data, hence you don't receive an onDataChanged() callback; Android Wear framework looks at the content of your data and decided if it is a new one or not and if it doesn't see any change in the content (assuming that its path doesn't change either), it won't considers that a new one. Add a timestamp to your data and that should make it a new data each time, and should trigger the callback:

```
putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
```